# Necessary and sufficient conditions for commutativy of Cartesian product of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B$ be sets. I know that $A\times B=B\times A$ if $A=B$ or $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$. But, is the converse also true? or what meaningful equivalence is known?

Comment: what do you mean by the converse ?

Comment: If $A\times B = B\times A,$ then $A=B$ or $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset.$

Answer (score 2):

The converse is indeed true.  Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both nonempty but $A\times B=B\times A$.  Pick elements $a_0\in A$ and $b_0\in B$.  Then for any $a\in A$, $(a,b_0)\in A\times B=B\times A$, which means $a\in B$ (and $b_0\in A$).  Similarly, for any $b\in B$, $(a_0,b)\in A\times B=B\times A$ so $b\in A$.  Thus $A=B$.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. Do you think I should eliminate my question because it is elementary?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with elementary questions on this site!  It might be a duplicate but I did some searching and (somewhat to my surprise) couldn't find an older version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assume $A, B\neq\emptyset$ and let $x\in B$ then $< x, b>\in A\times B$ for all $b\in B$ but we have $<x,b>\in B\times A$ so $x\in B$. $A\subset B$ the other direction is the same. I hope that helps